# Loop to return number from string given conditions R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have a question. I have a column indicating the district as a string `"district1"`, for example. However, now I would like to add another column with just number of the district. I am using if else statements but this is exhausting.

Below I give just a example of the more than 30 districts I have:

```
### generate dataframe
 d <- data.frame(variable=c("district1", "district1", "district1", "district1", "district2", "district2", "district3"))


 d$id1 = ifelse(d$variable=="district1", 1,
                        ifelse(d$variable=="district2", 2,
                               ifelse(d$variable=="district3", 3, NA)))
```

Thus I was wondering if it was possible to do it with a loop. However the looping structure is not well done:

```
#  for (i in 1:30){
#    d$id1 = ifelse(d$variable=="districti", i, NA) 
# }
```

Could someone help me to do in a more elegant way? This would be great
Best

Comment: Try a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/ool1aB/1), `gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", d$variable)`. Replace (`gsub`) all matches with the empty string `""`. No loops at all.

Comment: Also, in `d$variable=="districti"` the right way would be `d$variable==paste0("district", i)`. Or `sprintf("district%d", i)` instead of `paste0`.But the loop would still be wrong, you would be creating a column with all `NA` except for the match positions and be rewriting the previous matches each following iteration with a different `i`. Try it to see what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much. The gsub command works very well here.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for a solution like this:

```
library(tydiverse)
d %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  mutate(id = cur_group_id())

d %>% 
  mutate(id = str_remove_all(variable, pattern = "[a-zA-Z]"))

   variable id
1 district1  1
2 district1  1
3 district1  1
4 district1  1
5 district2  2
6 district2  2
7 district3  3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
d %>% 
 mutate(num = str_extract(variable, "\\d+"))
#   variable num
# 1 district1   1
# 2 district1   1
# 3 district1   1
# 4 district1   1
# 5 district2   2
# 6 district2   2
# 7 district3   3
```

Use `str_extract` to extract the number; `\\d+` matches digits at least one time